# Navision tables and value mapping

Tags: sql-server, navision

i m looking into Navision tables i have notice that in many cases there are numeric values which represent words.

For example:

In table **Sales Line** there is a column named **Document Type** which represent Quote, Order, Invoice, Credit Memo, Blanket Order, Return Order. In database table those Document Types are represented by numeric values, 1,2 etc.

Is there any website which provide the mapping among the words and the numeric values for each table?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I've found a diagram but I'm not sure of that what you are looking for: https://mibuso.com/downloads/navitools-er-diagram-v12-for-microsoft-navision  and this one: https://mibuso.com/downloads/tbrowser-v12

Comment: @MuzafferGalata thanks for you time & effort. i think that is not what i m looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn’t.

You can only get that mapping from inside Nav.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will find that info at https://dynamicsdocs.com/. Just be careful in how you read the entries. The values are zero-based arrays.

So for example, `[Value Entry].[Source Type]` is `[ ,Customer,Vendor,Item]`

Which means that 0 is skipped and the values are.

- 1 = Customer
- 2 = Vendor
- 3 = Item

And `[Value Entry].[Type]` is `[Work Center,Machine Center, ,Resource]` - notice that the values are 0, 1, 3, while 2 is skipped.